# install linux on headless computer - ideas, on what to do when you don't have external monitor

Tags: linux, installation

I need ideas. I have a headless linux box, I messed with it allot, and now it doesn't come online anymore / can't access SSH or VNC.

I've no ext monitor, so it will be hard to get something up running in total blindness.

Ideas:

## 1

I've HP laptop with internal card reader. I thought I would reinstall linux on laptop/SD setup SSH and VNC and than move it to server hoping hardware will be recognized.

Failed: Cannot boot from SD on laptop. Need external card reader so it's seen as USB device.

## 2

Use some kind of software, visualization soft, to install linux on SD card. And than move it to server.

What do you think? Specific advices appreciated!

- should I raid neighbors for old CRT or smth? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved problem in this manner:

1. Unplug SSD/HDD from laptop.
2. Connect ubuntu USB bootable dongle.
3. Connect empty usb HardDisk.
4. Install on usbHDD - ext4 - /
5. Load from usbHDD and setup remoote view and SSH.
6. Load from ubuntu usb bootable dongle again.
7. Shrink usbHDD partition to the size of the SD card (7gb in my case)
8. Use command DD under ubuntu to copy bite after bite from usbHDD to SDHC.
9. Connect SD card to server and fire it up - AND IT WORKS!

:)

Answer (score 1):

- Option 1, prepare a USB or CD livecd image that will boot the linux box, start up the network, and enable an SSH server.  For this to work, the system must already be set to boot of a USB or CD-ROM in the BIOS.  This is pretty easy to do with [SystemRescueCd](http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page)
- Option 2, again, prepare, and boot off a livecd.  But instead of using SSH and the network, get yourself a Serial Null modem cable.  Connect the computers via RS-232.  Startup putty, and use your computer as an actual terminal.
- Option 3, Pull the hard drive out, mount it as an external hard drive on your main computer, make it visible in virtual box or something, and fix the install.  Then put it back into the computer

Comment: Hi,

Option 3. I downloaded VirtualBox. Is that the right program for procedure? Will I be able to mount ext3 SD on virtualBOX in win7?